# probability of non of the urns empty

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, problem-solving

So I have

- $10$ balls, and $6$ urns

All of the balls and urns are numbered/labeled. This tells me that everything is unique.

The question is, what is the probability that none of the urns are empty.

**Attempt**

$Pr($None are empty$)= Pr($all are full$)=Pr($I not empty$)*Pr($II not empty$)*...Pr($VI not empty)
In a previous problem I found the probability of Urn $I$ to be empty as $\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$ So the probability of Urn $I$ not empty is 1-$\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$. Since the probability of any one urn to be empty is the same. its 6*(1-$\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$). This doesn't feel right based on the answer solutions in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017772/probability-that-none-of-the-urns-remains-empty) appears to be similar however I am not sure how to extend that here.

I am not sure how to extend the answer solution there to this case either. Ball 1 has only 1 choices, urn $I$. Ball 2: has two choices($I, II) =>$ ($0.5$), ... Ball 6: =>$\frac{1}{6}$. However ball 7, 8, 9, 10 now has 6 choices. So does this mean that the $Pr($none are empty)=($\frac{1}{6!*6^3}$)

Answer (score 2):

By [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the probability in question is:
$$
\frac1{6^{10}}\sum_{i=0}^6(-1)^i\binom{6}i (6-i)^{10}\equiv\frac{6!}{6^{10}}{10\brace 6}\approx0.27,
$$
where ${m \brace n} $ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Okay, so the way that I am reading this, there are $6^{10}$ total to arrange the balls into urns. But since none are of the urns are empty, we can say that the first 6 balls that are chosen, have no choice of urns. the first ball goes into the first urn, second into second, and so on. There are $_{10}C_{6}$ ways to pick those first 6 balls. But, I am a little confused on the intuition and meaning on the $6!$.

Comment: Would it be that the first ball chosen has 6 choices of urns, 2nd ball chosen has 5 choices of urns, ..., 6th ball only has 1 choice of urns to go into?

Comment: @Lizzy I am sorry. I have misprinted.

Comment: @Lizzy Using PIE  we eliminate the cases (from the $6^{10}$ total) with empty urns.

Comment: so there are $6^{10}$ total, and we want to find the number ways that there can be an empty urn?

Comment: @Lizzy We subtract the events with empty urns correcting ourselves when we overshot.

Comment: @Lizzy You may find it easier to memorize the last expression  with Stirling number (which does the PIE job for you).

Comment: So..the number of times that one urn can be empty is $5^{10}$, two empty urns are $4^{10}$... five empty urns is $1^{10}$

Comment: @Lizzyl Almost. You need additionally multiply those by the number of ways to choose the empty urns.

Comment: $6 C5$ ways of one urn to be empty with probability of $\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$

Comment: @Lizzy Yes you got it. I would prefer to use $\binom61$ but this is question of taste.

Comment: Okay yeah, that makes sense, i was thinking of picking 5 urns with balls, because the probability is that the balls have 5 choices. But i can see how $6C1$ can make more sense

Comment: So now to make sure that I use PIE correctly. First I would $sum$ $6Cx$ *$ \frac{x^{10}}{6^{10}} $then subtract $6^{10}$ from the sum

Comment: No, first I would get the $\sum 6Cx$ then subtract this number by $6^{10}$. that will get me the number of events that has all urns filled. and then divide this by the $6^{10}$, to get the probability

Comment: @Lizzy The correct expression is given in my answer. You can compare explicitly expanding the sum. Don't forget the factor $(-1)^i $.

Comment: Okay, how does the binom in the formula $6 C$ $i$ become $10 C6$?

Comment: @Lizzy where do you see it?

Comment: " $\equiv\frac{6!}{6^{10}}{10\brace 6}$ " right after the Stirling formula

Comment: @Lizzy This is the Stirling number not the binomial coefficient.